# Symfony2 custom user provider can't retrieve user

Tags: email, symfony, authentication

I followed this [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) to implement my own custom user login. Unfortunately it says `Bad credentials` during login. This exception comes from line 72 of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider`. This exception gets thrown because it can't retrieve the user.

What I changed for my custom needs is that the users do not have a username. They will login with their email address. But I think that would be no problem to implement.

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**UserRepository:**

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
}
```

**login.twig.html:**

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" value="{{ email }}"

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

What have I done wrong here? In `UserRepository` it clearly queries the email as username, so why can't it find the user? I have the speculation that it has something to do with the `csrf_token`? How can I add it to the controller and twig file? Is this the problem at all oder is it anything else I did wrong?

Comment: Try to set `_username` field name insteadof `_email`.

Comment: Thx, now the exception gets thrown in line 89 instead of 72. But I think this still has something to do that it can't find the user?

Comment: Okay, the exception message is `The presented password is invalid.`. I don't get this. I have plaintext encoder and i double checked that the password is correct. What is wrong?

Comment: Okay, found it out. I forget that Symfony2 will ALWAYS use the salt. So now it works correct. If you want you can put your comment into a single answer which I can accept, because it was the answer of the primary problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Symfony security uses `_username` and `_password` parameters to authenticate user via form submit. You can see it in [security configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

```
form_login:
    username_parameter: _username
    password_parameter: _password
```

So you need to place `_username` field name insteadof `_email`.